# Complex Array to Compare Armor Sets

Tags: php, arrays, jagged-arrays

perhaps I'm having a dumb moment, but I just can't seem to work this out in my head.

I'll try and explain:-

I have three 'sets.' Each set contains 6 objects. I need a loop (or series of nested loops) to result every combination of these sets.

It's for a game, I'm trying to write a script to compare armor sets - sad I know. The array of sets looks like this:-

```
class => array(
  set1 => array(
    hat item => array(stats)
    glove item => array(stats)
    ...
  set2 => array(
    hat item => array(stats)
    ...
  set3 => array(
    ...

)
```

This may be a lot simpler (or a lot more difficult?) than I thought.

Ideas welcome!

Thanks,
Ruu.

EDIT:-

Ok here's an array sample, I've stripped out a LOT of the extra stats, and just left one for each piece:-

```
$setinfo = array(
    'rk' => array(
        'set1' => array(
            'hat' => array(
                'will' => 114,
            ),
            'shoulders' => array(
                'will' => 78,
            ),
            'shirt' => array(
                'will' => 78,
            ),
            'gloves' => array(
                'will' => 78,
            ),
            'trousers' => array(
                'will' => 78,
            ),
            'boots' => array(
                'will' => 114,
            ),
        ),
        'set2' => array(
            'hat' => array(
                'will' => 78,
            ),
            'shoulders' => array(
                'will' => 78,
            ),
            'shirt' => array(
                'will' => 114,
            ),
            'gloves' => array(
                'will' => 78,
            ),
            'trousers' => array(
                'will' => 114,
            ),
            'boots' => array(
                'will' => 78,
            ),
        ),
        'set3' => array(
            'hat' => array(
                'will' => 78,
            ),
            'shoulders' => array(
                'will' => 114,
            ),
            'shirt' => array(
                'will' => 78,
            ),
            'gloves' => array(
                'will' => 114,
            ),
            'trousers' => array(
                'will' => 78,
            ),
            'boots' => array(
                'will' => 78,
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

From this example (I will worry about comparing other stats later,) the 'ideal' pieces would be, the hat and boots from set1, with the shirt and trousers from set2, and the gloves and shoulders from set3.

My query is how best to work out a loop which can generate a 'result' array with every permutation, for comparison later.

Comment: Just add your full array and expected output ... you have have to make your question look like a game too

Comment: Please provide more input and what exactly you want as output.

Comment: Sounds like you want to looking at permutations.

Comment: What you want is called a cartesian product, if I remember my math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an implementation from [this guy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php#54979):

```
function array_cartesian_product($arrays)

{
    $result = array();
    $arrays = array_values($arrays);
    $sizeIn = sizeof($arrays);
    $size = $sizeIn > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    foreach ($arrays as $array)
        $size = $size * sizeof($array);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i ++)
    {
        $result[$i] = array();
        for ($j = 0; $j < $sizeIn; $j ++)
            array_push($result[$i], current($arrays[$j]));
        for ($j = ($sizeIn -1); $j >= 0; $j --)
        {
            if (next($arrays[$j]))
                break;
            elseif (isset ($arrays[$j]))
                reset($arrays[$j]);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
$combinations = array_cartesian_product($sets);
```

Here is a simple test case: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/m1i-w7m

Comment: At first glance, works, spits out a 512-element array, which is what I was expecting. However, each element only has 3 items in it, when I was expecting 6 items per combination?

Comment: It takes one element from each set, so provided your sets are: a set of all hats, a set of all boots, a set of all gloves etc., you should get all possible combinations. Also, updated the test, my sets were wrong.

Comment: It works! Had to re-arrange my array though. Inititally I had three arrays of 6-element sets, I've just refactored it to be 6-sets of three-item arrays. Eg, instead of set1(hat1, boot1, glove1), set2(hat2, boot2, glove2), it's now hats(1, 2), boots(1, 2), gloves(1, 2). Thanks! XD